# How to create a background using a circle and a rectangle in XML

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I want to create such a background using XML, how can I combine them
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code for the background.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:bottom="0dp"
    android:left="0dp"
    android:right="0dp"
    android:top="0dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/black"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item
    android:bottom="-100dp"
    android:left="-220dp"
    android:right="-130dp"
    android:top="100dp">
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="@color/colorRed"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

[This will show like this. result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwjMh.png)

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to do such designs in Android studio.

Easier way I know to create them is using Adobe XD. Here, you can create the required design, then export in SVG format, which can be directly imported from Android studio. This will be created as an XML file in your project.

You can refer this tutorial video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=46emdTv8Js4

Answer (score 0):

1- create background_balck.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:shape="rectangle" >
<solid android:color="#000"/>
</shape>
```

2- create file  forground_shape.xml and put this code on it in drawable.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item>
     <shape android:shape="rectangle" />
</item>
<item
    android:bottom="-70dp"
    android:left="-150dp"
    android:right="-100dp"
    android:top="100dp">
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="#F40505" />
    </shape>
   </item>
 </layer-list>
```

2- set this shape to any view like this.

exmaple:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background_balck"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="423dp"
    android:layout_height="734dp"
    android:background="@drawable/forground_shape"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2">

         ///your  component

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


    /// root view 

  <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="51dp" />

  </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

result :
[image]

have fun :)